# How to transform data in order to visualize it with my own drawing software?

Tags: data-visualization, dataset, normalization, barplot

I want to build my own data visualization toolset using Blender3D and Python.

Let's think of a racing bar chart. As a dataset, I have 'google search frequencies of 10 keywords over a period of 10 years'. As one might expect, the numbers I am dealing with are in the scale of millions and they change rapidly by time.

In Blender3D(+python), I know how to resize a bar and I know how to order bars in respect to their heights. This means that I have all the necessary knowledge for the 'graphical' part of the problem.

However, for obvious reasons, I cannot display bars in the heights of millions. So I need to normalize all my values, say, between 0-10.
Sometimes, as we move forward in time in our dataset, a value might really get ahead of all other values, rendering even the previous 'maximum' merely as a small number. When this happens, the values should be getting smaller and bigger *between* the scale of 0-10, in respect to one another. **(when one bar gets super big, it squeezes other bars down)**

How can I achive these transformations? What is formula for such normalizations? How can inform myself on this topic?

When I search in internet, I only get "how to plot in matplotlib... etc...". But I don't want to use any modules. *(or better yet, is there a package to give me the transformed values I need? So I can easily plug them into my code)*

For a better example, consider the racing bar graph in this website. Notice how 'covid' bar is squeezing other bars down: https://www.cochranetoday.ca/beyond-local/bar-chart-race-shows-rapid-rise-of-global-covid-19-deaths-2412222

I am already using a simple formula for normalizing my data. And it is giving me quite unexpected results. For example, a value '0' is going below '0', whereas it should have stayed as 0.
`(1+ (value - min)/(max-min))`

It would be a huge help if anybody could point me at the right direction! I am eager to learn more on this topic, yet I don't even know how to start searching. All the search results are already populated with answers like, how to achive it with an existing package...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The graphic you reference doesn't need any transformations: it dynamically adjusts the scale to accommodate the full range of data.  That doesn't require any data transformation at all.

Comment: yeah but how? Do they divide all numbers to the maximum? Or do they substract some certain amount from all bar chart values? My question is exactly this: How do you _dynamically_ adjust the scale to accommodate the full range of data? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the software.  In many graphics environments you just tell it what the range of values to plot is.  In fact, many such environments will automatically set the range so that all your values are displayed and not outside the plotting area.